# SSRS sum of row group for corresponding column

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that has row groups for customer MembershipLength (1 year account, 2 year account, etc.) then a sub group of rows for customer Status (active, inactive, etc.)  Then I have columns for customer types.

Ultimately I want to add a column that will calcualate the percentage of the subtotal for the corresponding customer type.  However, if I break it down and just try to get the sum of the row group for a customer type I can only get both customer types.  I only want the MembershipLength customer count for the corresponding customer type.

`=Sum(Fields!ZO.Value,"matrix1_MembershipLength")` will give me a total for both customer types when I only want it for the corresponding column `matrix1_CustomerType`

I posted the same question on the MSDN forum [HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/89fc0656-5042-4aa1-8d7a-eb4ab6974a90?prof=required) but haven't got the answer I am looking for yet. However, this might illustrate it better.

Comment: What are you talking about? Is this in a SQL database? An Excel spreadsheet? Something else?

Comment: "subtoatl"... isn't that one of the Mayan gods?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=sum(iif(Fields!CustType.Value="VIP",1,0))/count(Fields!CustomerName)
```

without a clearer explination this is all i can figure out.